# Folland's Real Analysis, Proposition 1.15

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am confused about the last part of the proof of Proposition 1.15 from Folland's Real Analysis, which states

> **Proposition 1.15 (pg33)** Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and right continuous. If $(a_j, b_j]$ are disjoint $h$-intervals,
> $$\mu_0 \Big(\bigcup_{j=1}^n (a_j, b_j] \Big) := \sum_{j=1}^n [F(b_j)-F(a_j)]$$
> and let $\mu_0 ( \emptyset) = 0 $. Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

In the proof given by the book, after showing that $\mu_0$ is well defined and that $\mu_0$ is finitely additive by construction, it remains to show

> If $\{I_j\}_0^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint h-intervals with $\bigcup_{j=1}^n I_j \in \mathcal{A}$ then $\mu_0(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} I_j) = \sum_0^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)$.

It is relatively easy to obtain $\mu_0(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} I_j) \geq \sum_0^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)$, so we focus on showing $\mu_0(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} I_j) \leq \sum_0^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)$. We assume $I := \bigcup_{j=1}^n I_j = (a,b]$ and discuss the situations when

(i) $a$ and $b$ are finite
(ii) $a = -\infty$ and
(iii) $b = \infty$.

This is how the book does the proof:

[image: see image here]

I understand the case when $a$ and $b$ are finite, but I'm confused about how to apporach the cases of $a = -\infty$ and $b = \infty$.
Can one show me more detailed proof of this part (more detailed than the last paragraph in the above image)? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! This may have been initially closed because images are not accessible to some users, or because many users desire to see as much as possible presented in the form of text (and dislike questions that rely on links to photos of printed material, as distinguished e.g. from embedded images of diagrams that are not otherwise reproducible in text).  Images can also interfere with the ability of users to discover this or related questions via text search.

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation of the text, but I believe Folland wants to define

$$
\mu_0((-\infty,b]) = F(b) + (-1)\inf_x F(x)\quad\text{and}\quad\mu_0((-a,+\infty]) = \sup_xF(x) - F(a)
$$

similarly for $\mu_0(\mathbb{R})$. Notice we side-stepped the subtraction of infinities. Sending $M\to\infty$ will show

$$
\mu_0(I)\leq\biggl(\sum_{j\geq 1}\mu_0(I_j)\biggr)+2\varepsilon
$$

This holds for every $\varepsilon>0$. The reverse inequality comes from another equation at the top of the page.

However, I may also point out that the proof is incomplete, since we have not proven the well-definedness for these unbounded intervals. But that is another story.